# Key combo using CGEvent in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to press Ctrl+Right-Arrow (this should switch my window to the right window) key combo through software.  I am using CGEvents to press the Ctrl key and then press the right arrow key (while the Ctrl key is still pressed), but my window does not change.

```
//
//  main.m
//
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
// CGEvent functions
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

// kVK_* values
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int virtualKeys[] = {kVK_Control, kVK_RightArrow };
    CGEventSourceRef sourceRef = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

    // press the Ctrl key
    CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(sourceRef, virtualKeys[0], true);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);

    // press the right arrow key
    CGEventRef event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(sourceRef, virtualKeys[1], true);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event2);

    // wait .1 seconds
    usleep(100000);

    // release the right arrow key
    event2 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, virtualKeys[1], NO);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event2);
    CFRelease(event2);

    // release the ctrl key
    event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, virtualKeys[0], NO);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
    CFRelease(event);
}
```

This code is run via xcode.

Comment: I'm not sure that the docs are telling the truth about the need to send separate events to push the control key down and up.  Try: `CGEventSetFlags( event2, kCGEventFlagMaskControl )`